# Petition Software / Site — Alternatives to Change.org and MoveOn?

Tags: gratis, open-source

I am looking for a petition software / site with these characteristics:

- Embeddable HTML form (for third-party website, an option that Change.org had and appears to have removed)
- Asks people to share after signing (email, Twitter, FB, etc)
- Gives our organization a copy of the signer's email
- Does not datamine / abuse emails of signers
- Credible repository (in the way that a spreadsheet from a Google Form is not)

Comment: Will this be self-hosted? That is, are you asking us to recommend some software for you, or an existing web site?

Comment: It can be self-hosted on WordPress, but perhaps it is more credible if it's not self-hosted? A non-profit / org (unlike Change.org, which is a B corp that appears to sell data) would be ideal. We can pay for the service. Thanks

Comment: The point I am trying to make here is that we recommend software applications, not hosting services. I fear this is not on topic, as per https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: If this isn't the place for this, I don't know what is. I tried posting in politics and they sent me here.

Comment: @Mawg I disagree. He seems to be asking for a web app, not a hosting service. Requests for web apps are on-topic.

Comment: I wish that he would read [ask], and make that clear. To me it is totally ambiguous and there is a danger that it will be closed. GIGO; unclear requests don't tend to get answers which satisfy the OP. I ***am*** trying to be helpful :-)